# Start Loop in php

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I am trying to create series of continuous stars. but output is wrong. im not getting where i am wrong here. Do i have to add one more loop?

```
for ($i=1; $i<=6; $i++)         
{  
    for ($p=1; $p<=4; $p++)         
    { 
        for ($k=6; $k>$i; $k--)  
        {   
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";   
        }

        for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++)   
        {    
            echo "*"; 
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 
        }
    }

    echo "&nbsp;";     
    echo "<br>"; 
}
```

The resulting output:
[image: This is result]

Comment: What is the result do you expect?

Comment: shown in picture. like first triangle.

Comment: do you want the 1st triangle to repeat 4 times?

Comment: https://eval.in/1056937 - it works

Comment: yes sir 1st triangle to repeat 4 times.

Comment: @splash58 it is not working :(

Comment: Let me improve your code

Comment: @bhagwantSingh and what a result do you want?

Comment: @splash58 1st triangle to repeat 4 times

Comment: @RinsadAhmed ok sir :)

Comment: Be sure to set monospaced font to get correct result ;)

Comment: Well you ain't going to learn much if somebody else does the job for you. This is a simple logical and mathematical problem to solve. If I were you I would start with a blank paper and a pencil and try to do the math.

Comment: @bhagwantSingh find my answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's a piece of code that will generate the pattern you are looking for. For formatting on SO I've used space and newline, you can replace those with `&nbsp;` and `<br/>` as required:

```
for ($r = 0; $r <= 5; $r++) {
    for ($t = 1; $t <= 4; $t++) {
        for ($s = -5; $s <= 5; $s++) {
            echo ' ' . ((abs($s) <= $r) && (abs($s) % 2 == $r % 2) ? '*' : ' ') . ' ';
        }
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
                *                                *                                *                                *                
             *     *                          *     *                          *     *                          *     *             
          *     *     *                    *     *     *                    *     *     *                    *     *     *          
       *     *     *     *              *     *     *     *              *     *     *     *              *     *     *     *       
    *     *     *     *     *        *     *     *     *     *        *     *     *     *     *        *     *     *     *     *    
 *     *     *     *     *     *  *     *     *     *     *     *  *     *     *     *     *     *  *     *     *     *     *     *
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

You need to output equal number of chars for every row. You print chars before `'*'`, so just print chars after the `'*'`.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$star = '*';
$char = '&nbsp;';
for ($i=1; $i<=6; $i++) {  
    for ($p=1; $p<=4; $p++) {  
        for ($k=6; $k>$i; $k--) {   
            echo $char;   
        } 
        for($j=1; $j<=$i; $j++) {    
            echo $star; 
            echo $char;   
        }
        for ($k=6; $k>$i; $k--) {   
            echo $char;   
        } 
        echo $char.$char.$char;     
    }
    echo "<br>"; 
}
?>
```

**Output:**

```
     *              *              *              *         
    * *            * *            * *            * *        
   * * *          * * *          * * *          * * *       
  * * * *        * * * *        * * * *        * * * *      
 * * * * *      * * * * *      * * * * *      * * * * *     
* * * * * *    * * * * * *    * * * * * *    * * * * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

You code was almost working fine. A few tweaks needed to your code. Please find the working code

```
for ($i=1; $i<=6; $i++){  
for ($p=1; $p<=4; $p++)         
{ 
    for ($k=6; $k>$i; $k--)  
    {   
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";   
    } 
    for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++)   
    {    
        echo "*"; 

        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 

    }

    for ($k=6; $k>$i; $k--)  
    {   
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";   
    }
}
echo "&nbsp;";     
echo "<br>"; 
}
```